# Disabling saying extensions when the ext is not available with Asterisk?

Tags: voip, asterisk, pbx

I setup Asterisk and everything works great. The main issue I have is that when the external call cannot reach the default extension, the system repeats the extension number which could be desirable in many situations but not in my. Basically I would like the default extension to pick up the call (which does now), but I do not want system to say the extension number before directing the caller to the voice main. Because this is a home system and most of my callers would be just confused about the extensions. I just would like it to be feel like a standard voice mail, without additional information about the internal system.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use hints or device state to do that.

Unfortanly you not provided any dialplan info so no way help you.

http://www.asteriskdocs.org/en/3rd_Edition/asterisk-book-html-chunk/DeviceStates_id265377.html